# Are the iPhone 4 charger and iPod 4 charger different?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, charger

Are the iPhone 4 charger and iPod 4 charger different? I can charge my iPhone with both, but my iPhone charger will not charge my iPod. (I'm thinking it might be the length of the 30-pin connector, because the iPod touch is curved)
I know the outlet and wall adapter work.

Answer (score 3):

No, they aren't.
Here you can find the two type of charger, [5W](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD810LL/A/apple-5w-usb-power-adapter?fnode=74) (iPod and iPhone charger) and [12W](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD836LL/A/apple-12w-usb-power-adapter?fnode=74) (iPad, iPod, iPhone charger) with compatibility list.
The length of 30 pin connector is always the same (it is standardised for Apple).

Comment: You do mean the length, right? (Front to back)

Comment: I mean the length of the metal connector (pin) is always the same. So it is fully compliant with iPhone and iPod (even if it is curved).

Comment: With my iPhone charger, I've found that it has to be inserted a little more than comfortable into my iPod for it to charge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the same and you can charge them with both which is very handy.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?